# Display negative reputation for reputation graph (graph below reputation link in Summary)

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

By reputation graph I mean the graph that's below the Reputation link (only if you have rep changed in the last week or something like that).

---

## Display lost/negative reputation on reputation graph

Right now the reputation graph looks like that it only displays the positive achievements and does not display negative reputation changes. It shows the negative rep (not displays) when you hover over the date you lost reputation.

If the user did not hover over the dates he/she might get confused and think the rep didn't change for that user on the date he/she actually lost reputation.

Maybe it then should look like this (ignore the reputation changes shown):

[image: reputation graph with negative rep shown]

If it doesn't fit, just add some space.

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica: That's a different graph. This question is about the graph on the Summary tab, not under Reputation->Graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view more information, you can currently go to the Graph tab. If you click on that, you can view the graph, which includes negative reputation.

[image: Reputation tab with a freehand circle around the Post, Time, and Graph sub-tab menu]

It seems that showing only positive reputation changes is intentional.

[image: Reputation summary when no positive reputation have happened recently]